# Reference table rows by automatic counter

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, numbering

**Problem**

I have defined an environment to automatically number example sentences throughout my document. It uses the tabular environment and automatically numbers the first column of each row using a custom counter. I have reasons for not using lists or the theorem counter.

I want to label and reference a table row so that the number associated with the row is displayed. Using `\label` and `\ref` does not work. Is there some way to feed a function two args, a key and the current value of my counter, and later use the key to recall the other arg? Or is there another way to do what I want? Not breaking the labels and references for the rest of the document is ideal but not necessary.

**(Non-)Working Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} %don't know why this is needed; get csname error otherwise

% automatically number examples throughout document
\newcounter{exno}
\newenvironment{examples}
{
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{>{(\stepcounter{exno}\theexno)}rl}
}
{
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
Here are some numbered example sentences.
\begin{examples}
  &Content of row 1 \label{row1} \\
  &Content of row 2 \label{row2}
\end{examples}
Now I want to get a 1 here: \ref{row1}. I want to get a 2 here: \ref{row2}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order for you to reference the counter like that you need to use `\refstepcounter`. This steps the counter, as well as telling `LaTeX` to use the supplied counter for the following reference.

Then you need to replace the `\label`'s. They need to address directly to the counter. Therefore your example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} %don't know why this is needed; get csname error otherwise

% automatically number examples throughout document
\newcounter{exno}
\newenvironment{examples}
{
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{>{(\refstepcounter{exno}\theexno)}rl}
}
{
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
Here are some numbered example sentences.
\begin{examples}
  \label{row1} &Content of row 1 \\
  \label{row2} &Content of row 2
\end{examples}
Now I want to get a 1 here: \ref{row1}. I want to get a 2 here: \ref{row2}.

\end{document}
```

This will produce:
[image: example]

**Added**: This also works by linking to the row by loading `hyperref` package.

Comment: Thanks! :^) That works nicely. It seems `\label` has to go immediately after `\refstepcounter` in order to work.?

Comment: @Rachel, yes. :)

Comment: Anybody attempted to apply this solution within LyX?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris in LyX you are still capable of adding custom code... So this should be no problem. I can't see why it should not work... :)

Comment: @zeroth I was not clear, apologies. The problem is not putting the above code-example within an ERT. I rather try to get things done _without_ defining a long table structure + contents by hand. For example, putting a LyX-table inside an "examples"-like environment.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I have no experience in LyX. I would suspect that LyX is quite capable of that (otherwise tables would be quite similar)! Ask a question about this or search around for it. This is not generally limited by my solution but is a general question about table environments.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to zeroth's solution, but if one put the label definition in the `\newenvironment` it is more comfortable. So you don't need to create a label for each row manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} %don't know why this is needed; get csname error otherwise

% automatically number examples throughout document
\newcounter{exno}
\newenvironment{examples}
{
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{>{(\refstepcounter{exno}\theexno\label{row:\theexno}) }rl}
}
{
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
Here are some numbered example sentences.
\begin{examples}
&Content of row 1 \\
&Content of row 2
\end{examples}
Now I want to get a 1 here: \ref{row:1}. I want to get a 2 here: \ref{row:2}.

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
After zeroth's comment I edit my post to show how it works with more than one example. Just use an other counter for the example-environments. Or give each environment an unique name (as argument) and use it instead of the example-counter. Than it is possible to reference to the example and to the table rows. I think a lot of LaTeX environments works this way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} %don't know why this is needed; get csname error otherwise

% automatically number examples throughout document

%link the RowNumberCounter to the ExampleNumberCounter
\newcounter{ExampleNumber}
\newcounter{RowNumber}[ExampleNumber]

\newenvironment{examples}
{
\stepcounter{ExampleNumber}
%
\begin{flushleft}%
\begin{tabular}{>{%
(\refstepcounter{RowNumber}\theRowNumber%
\label{Example:\theExampleNumber:Row:\theRowNumber}) }rl}%
}
{%
\end{tabular}%
\end{flushleft}%
}%

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
Here are some numbered example sentences.
\begin{examples}
&Content of row 1 \\
&Content of row 2
\end{examples}
Now I want to get a 1 here: \ref{Example:1:Row:1}. I want to get a 2 here: \ref{Example:1:Row:2}.

\begin{examples}
&Content of row 1 \\
&Content of row 2\\
&Content of row 3 \\
&Content of row 4
\end{examples}
Now I want to get a 1 here: \ref{Example:2:Row:1}. I want to get a 2 here: \ref{Example:2:Row:2}.
Now I want to get a 3 here: \ref{Example:2:Row:3}. I want to get a 4 here: \ref{Example:2:Row:4}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I have considered this alteration. :^) It may be useful sometime, but it means that the key changes with the numbering, so you have to change your arguments to `\ref` as well.

Comment: This is dangerous if having several example environments. Then you have the same labels for different tables. Not recommended! Of course you could do with an extra argument of the environment which creates the label prefix, however, be aware! :)

Comment: @zeroth : I can't see any problems. I edit my post to show how it works with more than one example.

Comment: @Holle I still think that your approach of having a counter in the label like that is bad practice. What if you change chapters so that tables are interchanged? Instead do `\newenvironment{...}[1]{...\label{#1:\theRowNumber}}{...}`. Furthermore, what if you added a row in the middle. Now you have possible wrong refs in the text. It is a matter of taste, I just would never do it like that.

Comment: @zeroth Your arguments convinced me. You are right!

Answer (score 0):

I have following additional requirements

- named labels (and not autogeneratd ones) for each row, because I sometimes exchange rows.
- allow first column to be centered.
- `cleveref` support.
- similar appearance as the `algorithmic` environment.

I couldn't get `cleveref` to work, therefore, I'm using `autoref`.

Therefore, I came up with that solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\newcommand{\rowcountautorefname}{Line}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{{\makebox[1.3em][r]{\footnotesize\the\numexpr\value{rowcount}+1\relax:}}\hspace*{1.5\tabcolsep}}>{\refstepcounter{rowcount}}c}
line 1 \\
long line 2 \\
\label{line3} longer line 3
\end{tabular}

\autoref{line3} shows the longest line.

\end{document}
```

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58139/9075 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54892/9075.