# How to enumerate the rows of a table

Tags: tables, numbering

I want to automatically enumerate the text rows of a table. Is there an  option within `tabular`,  or another package? (Of course I do not want the rules to be enumerated.)

Comment: Duplicate question: [Automatic table row numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First define your own counter -- in this case `rowcount`. Now you can use the the declaration by `@{}` to print out the counter:

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount.)\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}ll}
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The alignment of the row numbers can be down by adding a `\makebox` with a specific with and adjustment.

```
\makebox[3em][r]{\therowcount.)}
```

In this case the number `rowcount` will be printed in a box with a width of 3em and right aligned.

[image]

---

**Colored Background**

To get a colored background you can use packages like `tcolorbox`, `framed`, `mdframed` or `adjustbox`

Here an example with `adjustbox`. <strike>Unfortunately there is no fontcolor option.</strike>

In the newest of of `adjustbox` the author Martin Scharrer provided a new key `fgcolor` to setup the font color of the environment.

https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/changeset/943f7cb95271

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\adjustbox{bgcolor=black, tabular=@{\stepcounter{rowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{white}\therowcount.)}\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}>{\color{white}}l>{\color{white}}l}{% 
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
foo & bar\\
} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to make the number in DESC order?

Comment: @Forgiver: What is *DESC order*?

Comment: From the highest number to the lowest.

Comment: @Forgiver: Therefor you can use the package `totcount`. See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58221/amsthm-theorems-lemmas-numbered-backwards/58240#58240

Comment: How can you skip a row count so that it starts, lets say in the third row?

Comment: @azetina: You can use `\setcounter`.

Comment: How can we set the enumerations to count in Roman numerals (e.g., i, ii, ...) instead of digits (e.g., 1, 2, ...)?

Comment: How to use \setcounter to skip the first row?  I tried \setcounter{1} but it can only change the number of the first row to 2.

Comment: @user21916: Put `\multicolumn{1}{>{\makebox[3em][r]{}}l}{foo} & bar\\ ` in the first row.

Comment: @Chernoff you can use `\roman{\therowcount}` to get lowercase roman numerals. Other options are `\Roman{}` for upper case roman numeral (I, II, ...), `\alph{}` for lower case letters (a, b, ...) and `\Alph{}`. Default is `\arabic{}`.

Comment: What if there is a header, and I only want to show the number as of the next line, and in header show the column title, like # ?!

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Daniel I have a \hline between all of my rows. This also gets a number using this method. Is there a way to make the numbering skip rows like this?

Comment: To be able referencing a row, one needs to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. See [Reference table rows by automatic counter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54881/9075).