# stepcounter and tabular environment

Tags: tables, numbering, counters

I am trying to generate a numbered table.  I used the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58138/how-to-enumerate-the-rows-of-a-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) here, which put `@{\stepcounter{rowcount}}` into the first line of the tabular.

However, this seems to break when I try to use the `booktabs` package, or even the plain tabular format.  I suspect the problem is because `\stepcounter` is fragile, but I don't know how to solve the problem.

I'd also like to make the first row a header, without a number.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcounter{rowcounter}
\setcounter{rowcounter}{0}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\stepcounter{rowcounter}\arabic{rowcounter}}ll} 
header row & text0\\ 
first row & text1\\
second row & text1\\
third row & text2

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't use `array` you need to `\protect` the commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcounter{rowcounter}
\setcounter{rowcounter}{0}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\protect\stepcounter{rowcounter}\protect\arabic{rowcounter} }ll} 
header row & text0\\ 
first row & text1\\
second row & text1\\
third row & text2

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you want to start at 0 then you could either initialise to -1 instead of 0 or in the `@{}`  use the counter before you increment it rather than after.

Comment: Can you modify this to show how to make header row?  I don't want the header row with 0, I want no number at all.  Is having an if/then clause the best way?  I tried having 2 tabular environments—one with header, the other with data— but can't get them aligned.  And this may be an inefficient way to do it.

Comment: @Tim just use `\multicoloumn{1}{@{}c}{header row}` and that cell will not get the `@{}` from the preamble.

Comment: yes it worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

In preamble you need add `array` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,  % <-- added
            booktabs}
\newcounter{rowcounter}
\setcounter{rowcounter}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\stepcounter{rowcounter}\arabic{rowcounter}\ }ll}
header row & text0\\
first row & text1\\
second row & text1\\
third row & text2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `array` is a good thing but it's not strictly needed here:-)

Comment: i see now in your answer. good to know  :)

Comment: preferred the answer of @David because didn't require `array`

Comment: @Tim I'll take the points, thanks:-) but you should use the `array` package almost always anyway. If we were doing it now we would have made that the default implementation of `tabular`, just not enough bytes available back in 1993.