# Can I reference the rows of an enumerated table?

Tags: tables, hyperref, longtable, labels

I have created a multi-page timeline using a `longtable` with enumerated rows (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58138/how-to-enumerate-the-rows-of-a-table)).

My MWE is as follows:

```
\begin{longtable}{@{\stepcounter{rowcount}(\therowcount)\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}l p{30em}}
   [date || blank] & [text] \\
   [...repeat...]
\end{longtable}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

My intention is to be able to then reference these numbers, similar to how court case reports are referenced via paragraph number. I've tried adding `\label{tl:{description}}`s but when I `\ref` them I just get the section number for the section of the document containing the timeline.

Is it possible to somehow reference the `rowcount` value for each row when referencing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question is

```
@{\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount.)\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}
```

There are two issues, Firstly you need `\refstepcounter` not `\stepcounter` so `\label` sees it, then secondly each `@{...}` is in its own scope so you probably want

```
@{}>{\refstepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount.)\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}
```

so then you can use `\label` in the first column

Comment: That's worked, but could you please elaborate on the difference between `@{...}` and `@{}>{...}`?

Comment: @Rumps `@` is inter-column material `>` injects the material into the start of each column cell.