# A question on table formatting

Tags: tables, amsmath, two-column

My task is to obtain what's being attached. The code too is appended. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

```
 \begin{minipage}[]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{Step}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $a=b$
    \item $a^2=ab$
    \item $a^2-b^2=ab-b^2$
    \item $(a-b)(a+b)=b(a-b)$
    \item $a+b=b$
    \item $2b=b$
    \item 2=1
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{Reason} \\
Given\\
Multiply both sides of (1) by $a$\\
Substract $b^2$ from both sides of (2)\\
Factor both sides of (3)\\
Divide both sides of (4) by $a-b$\\
Replace $a$ by $b$ in (5) because $a=b$ and simplify\\
Divide both sides of (6) by $b$
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Welcome! Your application fits a tabular, but with automatically numbered rows. I think that the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58138/how-to-enumerate-the-rows-of-a-table will answer your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcounter{aux}
\newcommand*{\al}{\stepcounter{aux}\theaux.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{p{.46\textwidth}p{.46\textwidth}}
    \textbf{Step}&\textbf{Reason}\\
    \al $a=b$&Given\\
    \al $a^2=ab$&Multiply both sides of (1) by $a$\\
    \al $a^2-b^2=ab-b^2$&Subtract $b^2$ from both sides of (2)\\
    \al $(a-b)(a+b)=b(a-b)$&Factor both sides of (3)\\
    \al $a+b=b$&Divide both sides of (4) by $a-b$\\
    \al $2b=b$&Replace $a$ by $b$ in (5) because $a=b$ and simplify\\
    \al $2=1$&Divide both sides of (6) by $b$
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It will give you this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! Could you pls let me know how to change the numbering to "bold" (1) ?

Comment: Sure. Where you have `\theaux.`, put `\textbf{\theaux.}` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The following is similar to the [answer of José Carlos Santos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625707/117050) but automates as much as possible utilizing the `array` package.

It automatically inserts `\mystep` at the start of each line (this will step a counter and insert it), and turns the contents of the first column into maths.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype\math[1]{>{$}#1<{$}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcounter{mystep}
\renewcommand*\themystep{\arabic{mystep}.}
\newcommand*\mystep{\refstepcounter{mystep}\themystep}
\newcommand*\resetmystep{\setcounter{mystep}{0}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\mystep\quad}\math{l} L}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Step}} & \textbf{Reason}\\% \multicolumn cancels the `\mystep\quad` and the `\math` column
  a=b               & Given \\
  a^2=ab            & Multiply both sides of (1) by $a$\\
  a^2-b^2=ab-b^2    & Substract $b^2$ from both sides of (2)\\
  (a-b)(a+b)=b(a-b) & Factor both sides of (3)\\
  a+b=b             & Divide both sides of (4) by $a-b$\\
  2b=b              & Replace $a$ by $b$ in (5) because $a=b$ and simplify\\
  2=1               & Divide both sides of (6) by $b$
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I would recommend using `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`, though, just in case the OP ever wants to cross-reference list entries via the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

Comment: @Mico yes, that seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution with OpTeX:

```
\newcount\trownum
\def\printrow{\ifnum\trownum>0 \hbox to1em{\hss\bf\the\trownum.}\else\tabiteml={}\fi\incr\trownum}

\table{(\printrow$)l($)l}{
  \bf Step          & \bf Reason \cr
  a=b               & Given \cr
  a^2=ab            & Multiply both sides of (1) by $a$ \cr
  a^2-b^2=ab-b^2    & Substract $b^2$ from both sides of (2) \cr
  (a-b)(a+b)=b(a-b) & Factor both sides of (3) \cr
  a+b=b             & Divide both sides of (4) by $a-b$ \cr
  2b=b              & Replace $a$ by $b$ in (5) because $a=b$ and simplify \cr
  2=1               & Divide both sides of (6) by $b$
}
\bye
```

And here is a solution with plain TeX and TeX primitives:

```
\newcount\trownum
\def\printrow{\global\advance\trownum by1 \hbox to1em{\hss\bf\the\trownum.}}

\vbox{\halign{\printrow\enspace$#$\hfil\quad &#\hfil\cr
  \omit\bf Step     & \bf Reason \cr
  a=b               & Given \cr
  a^2=ab            & Multiply both sides of (1) by $a$ \cr
  a^2-b^2=ab-b^2    & Substract $b^2$ from both sides of (2) \cr
  (a-b)(a+b)=b(a-b) & Factor both sides of (3) \cr
  a+b=b             & Divide both sides of (4) by $a-b$ \cr
  2b=b              & Replace $a$ by $b$ in (5) because $a=b$ and simplify \cr
  2=1               & Divide both sides of (6) by $b$ \cr
}}
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment has its own LaTeX counter for the rows, called `iRow`. Moreover, there is a mechanism of ``first row''. When the key `first-row` is set, the first row of the tabular correspond to the value 0 of the counter `iRow` (that's what you need here). Moreover, the command `\OnlyMainNiceMatrix` gives the ability to execute an instruction only in the main tabular (not in the so-called first row).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\OnlyMainNiceMatrix{\arabic{iRow}.\quad}}l X[l]}[first-row]
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
  Step                & Reason \\
  $a=b$               & Given \\
  $a^2=ab$            & Multiply both sides of (1) by $a$\\
  $a^2-b^2=ab-b^2$    & Substract $b^2$ from both sides of (2)\\
  $(a-b)(a+b)=b(a-b)$ & Factor both sides of (3)\\
  $a+b=b$             & Divide both sides of (4) by $a-b$\\
  $2b=b$              & Replace $a$ by $b$ in (5) because $a=b$ and simplify\\
  $2=1$               & Divide both sides of (6) by $b$
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tabularray` package and its `rownum` function:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {l Q[l, mode=math] X[l]},
             cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=\the\numexpr\arabic{rownum}-1.},
             row{1}  = {mode=text, font=\bfseries}
             }
    &   Step                & Reason \\
    &   a=b                 & Given \\
    &   a^2=ab              & Multiply both sides of (1) by $a$\\
    &   a^2-b^2=ab-b^2      & Substract $b^2$ from both sides of (2)\\
    &   (a-b)(a+b)=b(a-b)   & Factor both sides of (3)\\
    &   a+b=b               & Divide both sides of (4) by $a-b$\\
    &   2b=b                & Replace $a$ by $b$ in (5) because $a=b$ and simplify\\
    &   2=1                 & Divide both sides of (6) by $b$
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]