# Automatically number some rows in tabular

Tags: tables, setcounter

Is it possible to automate the numbering in a tabular like this?

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\hline
Step && Instruction \\\hline
   1  & & At this step we will \hfill \\\hline
 2 & & Then there is another step \\
 && then more \\
 & $\vert$ & this \\\hline
 3 && then some more text \\
 & $\vert$ & here is some more \\
 & $\vert$ & then some more \\\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create table with automatic row numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244153/create-table-with-automatic-row-numbering)

Comment: Unfortunately not as I don’t want every row to be numbered.

Comment: But if you want so manually select the rows, that should be numbered, how should this be automatically? Maybe you want to use a `p` column for the last column, so you can use linebreaks in the cell and indeed can automatically number each table row.

Comment: Maybe you should tell more about the real problem. If you just want to define and use a counter, see `\newcounter`, `\setpcounter` (or `\refstepcounter` if you want to refer to) and `\the<counter>`. Or maybe is shouldn't really be a table but simething like `align` with only some lines tagged? Even using `enumerate` and some items without numbering could be a suggestion. Sorry but it is unclear.

Comment: I think that will work perfectly. I wasn’t aware of that type of cell. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

One way is to use `tabularray` package. Using it you can write (based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685457)) the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{width=0.5\linewidth,
             hlines,
             colspec = {l X[l]},
             cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=\the\numexpr\arabic{rownum}-1},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries}  % if you liked boldface columns headers ...
             }
Step    &   Instruction                     \\
        &   At this step we will            \\
        &   {Then there is another step\\
                this}                 \\
        &   {then some more text\\
                here is some more\\
                then some more}       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An incredibly neat and efficient solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your formatting objective correctly, you wish to create a `tabular` environment with two columns; the left-hand column should display an automatically incremented row number, and the right-hand column will contain text and should allow automatic line wrapping. Moreover, there should be a mechanism to override the automatic display of a row number in the left-hand column, say, because you need to be able to typeset the word "Step" in the header row.

The following code achieves these goals. Observe that the utility macro called `\ZZ` -- feel free to choose a different name ... -- lets you override the automatic row numbering. `\ZZ{Step}` shows the word "Step"; `\ZZ{}` leaves the cell blank, and it doesn't increment the counter called `rownum`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{rownum}
\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{N}{% increment and display the value of 'rownum' counter
   >{\refstepcounter{rownum}\therownum}l}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{% suppress full justification
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand\ZZ[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{#1}} % macro to override action of 'N' col. type 
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} N P{3cm} @{}} % choose width of 2nd column as needed
\hline
\ZZ{Step} & Instruction \\
\hline
& At this step we will then more this \\
\hline
& Then there is another step then more this then \\
\hline
\ZZ{} & then some more text here is some more then some more then more  \\
\hline
& then some more text here is some more then some more then more more then more \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\setcounter{rownum}{0} % reset 'rownum' counter to 0
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} N P{3.5cm} @{}} % choose width of 2nd column as needed
\hline
\ZZ{Step} & Instruction \\
\hline
& At this step we will then more this \\
\hline
& Then there is another step then more this then more this \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```