# Need labels and refs in longtable rows

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, numbering, longtable

In a longtable, I need the first column to display numbers based on an enumeration by references to labels. This means I can refer to the rows somewhere else in the text.

I imagined it would help to create a label and reference to that label in the same cell, but I keep getting 1-figures instead of an incrementing number.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}


\hline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Title} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\label{row:thefirst}
\ref{row:thefirst} &
First \\
\hline

\label{row:thesecond}
\ref{row:thesecond} &
Second \\
\hline

\label{row:thethird}
\ref{row:thethird} &
Third \\
\hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I have tried changing the "row:" to something like "itm:" or "fig:", but nothing helps.

Perhaps, I need to put it in some context like when using `\begin{figure}`, but I am not sure how that would turn out when in a table cell.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: The "row:" is just a name *you* define. The funcionality isn't touched by this definition. (That's the reason why it did not help.)

Comment: Alright, but then what should I do to get to the numbers working...?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54881/reference-table-rows-by-automatic-counter?rq=1 help you?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\label` always refers to the last counter stepped with `\refstepcounter` (or actually whatever counter is saved in `\@currentlabel`), independently from the label name you choose. In your case it is the `table` counter as `\begin{longtable}` does `\refstepcounter{table}` internally. You need some counter that is stepped every row if you want to be able to refer to the rows.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The form of the label string has no effect whatsoever: it is an arbitrary internal string for cross referencing. You need to increment a counter if you want to count something.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\newcounter{ltrow}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{ltrow}{0}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\refstepcounter{ltrow}\theltrow}l|l|}


\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Number}} & \textbf{Title} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\label{row:thefirst}
 &
First \\
\hline

\label{row:thesecond}
 &
Second xxx\\    
\hline

\label{row:thethird} &
Third \\    
\hline

\end{longtable}


xxx is on row \ref{row:thesecond}
\end{document}
```