# Automatic counter with sub counter for table row - referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, tabularx, counters

I want something like this: a referrable automatic counter and sub counter for each row in a tabularx environment. I could find a solution for a single counter [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54881/reference-table-rows-by-automatic-counter), but could not adapt it to tabularx. So I tried implementing it directly using two counters. How do I reference the MainNumber counter and the SubNumber, without using the dirty solution in the last line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{MainNumber}
\newcounter{SubNumber}[MainNumber]

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
  \refstepcounter{MainNumber} \label{firstMain} \theMainNumber & This is first main. \\
  \refstepcounter{SubNumber} \label{1firstSub} \theMainNumber.\theSubNumber & This is first sub \\
  \refstepcounter{SubNumber} \label{1secondSub} \theMainNumber.\theSubNumber & This is second sub\\
  \refstepcounter{MainNumber} \label{secondMain} \theMainNumber & This is second main. \\   
  \refstepcounter{SubNumber} \label{2firstSub} \theMainNumber.\theSubNumber & This is first sub \\
  \refstepcounter{SubNumber} \label{2secondSub} \theMainNumber.\theSubNumber & This is second sub\\ 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

second main first sub:~\ref{2firstSub}

shoud be: 2.1

dirty: \ref{secondMain}.\ref{1firstSub}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This could be useful: `\renewcommand{\theSubNumber}{\theMainNumber.\arabic{SubNumber}}` so you don't need to type `\theMainNumber.\theSubNumber`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? The idea is to redefine the `\theSubNumber` (which contains the counter value) to have the format you want: `<main>.<sub>`.

So, you only type `\theSubNumber` instead of `\theMainNumber.\theSubNumber`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{MainNumber}
\newcounter{SubNumber}[MainNumber]
\renewcommand{\theSubNumber}{\theMainNumber.\arabic{SubNumber}} % <-- added here
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
  \refstepcounter{MainNumber} \label{firstMain}  \theMainNumber & This is first main. \\
  \refstepcounter{SubNumber}  \label{1firstSub}  \theSubNumber  & This is first sub \\
  \refstepcounter{SubNumber}  \label{1secondSub} \theSubNumber  & This is second sub\\
  \refstepcounter{MainNumber} \label{secondMain} \theMainNumber & This is second main. \\   
  \refstepcounter{SubNumber}  \label{2firstSub}  \theSubNumber  & This is first sub \\
  \refstepcounter{SubNumber}  \label{2secondSub} \theSubNumber  & This is second sub\\ 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

second main first sub:~\ref{2firstSub}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Another form of `automatic` numbering, by defining a new columntype, say, 'b' and letting the stepping and the display be done by the `b` type itself.

The code determines whether it should step the main counter or the sub counter by the boolean 'variable' `\ifstepmain` etc.

Since the code can't know when a new main step occurs (unless some more conditions are speficied) the switch to the main stepping must be done with `\prepnextmainstep`.

The usage of `tabularx` complicates the issue a little bit since `tabularx` tries to 'typeset' the tabular content multiple times, each time `\global` etc. settings have to be made.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{MainNumber}
\newcounter{SubNumber}[MainNumber]

\counterwithin{SubNumber}{MainNumber}



\newif\ifstepmain
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\ifstepmain\refstepcounter{MainNumber}\theMainNumber\global\stepmainfalse\else\refstepcounter{SubNumber}\theSubNumber\fi}l}

\newcommand{\prepnextmainstep}{%
  \global\stepmaintrue%
}

\stepmaintrue
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{bX}
    \label{firstMain}   & This is first main. \tabularnewline
    \label{1firstSub}   & This is first sub \tabularnewline
    \label{1secondSub}  & This is second sub \prepnextmainstep\tabularnewline  
    \label{secondMain}  & This is second main.\tabularnewline   
    \label{2firstSub}   & This is first sub \tabularnewline
    \label{2secondSub}  & This is second sub \prepnextmainstep \tabularnewline 
    \label{thirddMain}  & This is third main.\tabularnewline   
    \label{3firstSub}   & This is first sub \tabularnewline
    \label{3secondSub}  & This is second sub \prepnextmainstep \tabularnewline 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

second main first sub:~\ref{2firstSub} and \ref{3secondSub} 

shoud be: 2.1 and 3.2
\end{document}
```